# Couchbase: Deciding RAM size

Tags: couchbase

I need your help in deciding RAM size for couchbase server. Here is my requirements:

1. I have 1 TB disk space.
2. Expected load is 1k transactions p/s
3. We see more read volume compared to write volume.

Can you please suggest what value of RAM should I allocate and please help me understand how to arrive at the RAM memory figure?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sizing for 3.0 or 4.0? I ask as there are new services in 4.0 (Index and Query Services) that change the overall sizing.

Comment: Hi Kirk, I am sizing for 3.0. I tried sizing based on the formula given in the Couchbase site. But it didn't help me much.

Comment: What's your total data volume estimate? Depending on that, you may be able to have the whole data in RAM.

Comment: What is the average size of your objects, avg key size, how many total objects do you have, what percentage of those objects do you want to keep in the managed cache and how many replicas do you plan on keeping?

Comment: Hi Thank you all for your valuable help. I used the link: http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/bp-sizingGuidelines.html to do the sizing. My dataset size is not finalized yet, but took a approximate figure after consulting the business.

Figures considered:

documents_num =  10000000
ID_size       = 200
value_size   = 20000
number_of_replicas = 1
working_set_percentage = 40%

RAM size came up to approx 260 GB.